# Excess pressure in drops

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, bubbles

While calculating the excess pressure in a bubble or a drop, we consider one half of the bubble or a drop and equate the surface tension times the circumference of the half of the drop or bubble to excess pressure times area.

$$\tau \cdot c = P_{excess} \cdot A$$

Doesn't surface tension pull any point on the drop or bubble with equal force in all directions? Why should there be an excess pressure?

Answer (score 1):

If you do a force balance on a small element of surface on a balloon or drop (say, "window shaped"), there is curvature of the surface, and the surface tension forces acting at the edge of the element (or the elastic forces in the case of the balloon) have a net resultant in the radial direction.  This is why the pressure inside is higher than the pressure outside.  When you did your analysis, you just neglected the curvature effect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you call "excess pressure" what I call "capillary pressure". Take a look at this [figure](http://soft-matter.seas.harvard.edu/images/d/dd/Capcur_pdiff.png) from a wiki of a course at Harvard. The surface tension doesn't pull any point on the drop or bubble with equal force in all direction. Instead, it pulls the point in a direction that is tangential to the surface.